# Hovering at wrong place

Tags: html, css, hover

[image: Hover]
When I try to hover on the home button the hover effect is displayed above home icon instead on the home icon and home text itself. Check image for clear view. This occured when I added the home icon.How can I correct this. Thanks in advance!

```
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down section table-of-contents">
    <li>
        <a href="about.html" style="color:#fff;font-weight:bold;padding-right:50px"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is far too little code here to help. What hover? How hover? What CSS? Which element? Please post your code.

Comment: Please provide full code. Also, are you aware that your li element is broken?

Comment: correct your `li` closing and make sure the use of `padding-right`, may be `margin-right` is best.

Comment: gimme a min will post a codepen. Thought something wrong with the i tag placement only.Sorry

Comment: @FrayneKonok used margin-right no change. Whats wrong with li tag?

Comment: i edit your post see, and `li` closing was missed, padding is consider the space from inside and margin consider from outside.

Comment: Hey li closing was not missed. You have to scroll it a bit to see it. Thanks. But no change

Comment: ha ha check out the edit of your post and my edit....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103970/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-heblev).